# Webbynode gem conflicts (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, webbynode

I have installed Webbynode gem:

```
sudo gem install webbynode
```

but when I try some command, like:

```
wb help
```

display this error:

```
Unable to activate launchy-2.1.0, because addressable-2.3.2 conflicts with addressable (~> 2.2.6) (Gem::LoadError)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
gem uninstall addressable
```

So remove the conflicts gems, and should be only one addressable in the end.

It works for me.